# How to create unique constraint involving multiple properties in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I know I can create a unique constraint on a single property with Cypher like `CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE`. But I was wondering whether it is possible to create a unique constraint which involves multiple properties. If so, how?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

neo4j (2.0.1) does not currently support a uniqueness constraint that covers multiple properties simultaneously.

However, I can think of a workaround that might be acceptable, depending on your use cases. Let's say you want properties a, b, and c to be unique as a group. You can add an extra property, d, that concatenates the stringified values of a, b, and c, using appropriate delimiter(s) to separate the substrings (such that, for example, the a/b delimiter is a character that never appears in a or b). You can then create a uniqueness constraint on d.

[UPDATE]

Neo4j 3.3 added support for uniqueness constraints that cover multiple properties, via [node key constraints](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/constraints/#administration-constraints-node-key). However, this feature is only available in the [Enterprise Edition](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/introduction/#enterprise-edition).

[UPDATE]

Current versions of Neo4j Desktop now support:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT FOR (n:Person) REQUIRE (n.firstname, n.surname) IS NODE KEY
```

Comment: would you know if there are any plans for supporting this?

Comment: Hi any update on this? I am not finding this feature in latest version of Neo4j as well.

Answer (score 29):

As of neo4j version 3.3 there is a constraint called `NODE KEY` which can be used for uniqueness across multiple properties.

From the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/constraints/#query-constraint-node-key):

> To create a Node Key ensuring that all nodes with a particular label have a set of defined properties whose combined value is unique, and where all properties in the set are present

**Example Query**

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Person) ASSERT (n.firstname, n.surname) IS NODE KEY
```

Comment: Node Key constraint requires Neo4j Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 5):

As of now, neo4j(v3.0.3) still does not support unique constraint with multiple properties.
The reason behind this is:
`When a unique constraint is created it also creates an index on it and as indexes only allow one property, thus constraints can only be applied on one index.`

Comment: neo4j 3.2.1 supports composite index, so it might support composite constraint?