# Multiple properties of node to identify node Uniquely

Tags: neo4j

Can we have **multiple properties** of a node to identify it **uniquely** in **neo4j** graph database?

Something like composite primary key, in **RDBMS**, to uniquely identify a row of a table.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not.  The best that you can do at the moment is to create a property which concatenates the properties that you want to uniquely identify and put a constraint on that.

Comment: The answer to [this somewhat related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498054/how-to-create-unique-constraint-involving-multiple-properties-in-neo4j) provides a suggestion for how to concatenate.

Answer (score 4):

You can use an array property and create index on that.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, neo4j(v3.0.3) still does not support unique constraint with multiple properties. The reason behind this is: `When a unique constraint is created it also creates an index on it and as indexes only allow one property, thus constraints can only be applied on one index.`