# Using combination of attributes to set uniqueness in Cypher Query Language

Tags: neo4j, load-csv

I have a flight database in the form of csv with date and flight number among other columns.

```
date                        flight
01-01-2011 12:00                428
02-01-2011 12:00                428
03-01-2011 12:00                428
01-01-2011 12:00                429
02-01-2011 12:00                429
03-01-2011 12:00                429
```

So, on a particular date and time, multiple flights can be scheduled. I want to import this database in neo4j using cql creating a constraint on combination of date and flight number to be unique. My research says that combination of 2 attributes cant be used to set uniqueness. Is there any way to achieve this?

If I set an index on date, It also creates multiple relationships with other attributes when i just want one relationship.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create unique constraint involving multiple properties in Neo4J](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22498054/how-to-create-unique-constraint-involving-multiple-properties-in-neo4j)

Comment: Just use `merge` instead of `create`?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, one should use merge. I was using merge earlier too, but only on the date property. Once i used date and flight together in the merge statement, it solved my problem. Thanks.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Flights (date)
MERGE (flights:Flights {date: UPPER(line.`date`),flight_no: TOINT(line.`flight`)} )
```